# How do i resolve, "Namespace not specified" but I have specified it

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, namespaces, build.gradle

I recieve the following error when try to run my flutter project on the Android emulator

```
Namespace not specified. Please specify a namespace in the module's build.gradle file like so:

android {
    namespace 'com.example.namespace'
}

If the package attribute is specified in the source AndroidManifest.xml, it can be migrated automatically to the namespace value in the build.gradle file using the AGP Upgrade Assistant
```

I have a namespace specified, my AGP version is 8.0.2 and Gradle is 8.0.1 so I'm not sure what I am missing